# ReactDOM not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var ReactDom = require('react-dom')
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class')

//Create new react component
var TodoComponent = createReactClass({
    render:function() {
        return(
            <h1>React component</h1>
        )
    }
})

//Put react component in html page
ReactDom.render(<TodoComponent />, document.getElementById('todo-wrapper'))
```

This is my current code and its not rendering
Im pretty new to react

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, one major flaw with your code that I noticed is you used `ReactDom` instead of `ReactDOM` please refer to the react docs for further info on creating [class components and rendering them properly](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#making-an-interactive-component)

```js
class TodoComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      h1 > React component < /h1>
    )
  }
}

//Put react component in html page
ReactDOM.render( < TodoComponent / > , document.getElementById('todo-wrapper'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="todo-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, didnt see that earlier my bad

Comment: Its still not rendering even after i changed to that code

Comment: This balls down to how your app is structured, are you adding the react code in script tags in your HTML file as I did above, or you have a separate js file that you are calling in another HTML file?

Comment: I only have a main HTML file and a js file thats for the ReactDOM stuff

Comment: If you are using React via CDN, it is better to include your js in the HTML file inside a `<script type= 'text/babel'>[react script]</script>` tag

Comment: But i installed react via npm, do i still need the CDN

Comment: If you installed react via npm then, use the `import React from "react";` syntax to import react instead, add this to the top of your js file

Comment: Ive done everything and tried everything and the h1 component is still not showing up

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code, showing what you have currently and share?

Comment: Fixing the issue with your fiddle was relatively easy [here is my fix in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqve/kwvejm1c/6/), but I don't think it's a permanent fix for your local application, if the error you are getting is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` this is because you aren't using babel to transform your jsx, else if it's `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` then when importing your script into your HTML add the `type="module"` attribute to it e.g `<script type="module" src="/app/bundle.js"></script> ` try these locally and tell me if it works.